# Keras output names are incorrect when tf ops are used as outputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

I'm having trouble setting output names correctly in a Keras model.

The use case here is a Tensorflow Serving model, which names inputs and outputs based on the layer names.

Inputs are easy enough to name. But outputs, if they aren't instances of `keras.Layer`, don't seem to have their names properly set as the output names in the model.

See the following example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

input_0 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,), name="my_input_0")
x = keras.layers.Dense(units=1)(input_0)
output_0 = tf.math.log(x, name="my_output_0")
output_1 = tf.math.exp(x, name="my_output_1")

inputs = {
    "my_input_0": input_0
}

outputs = {
    "my_output_0": output_0,
    "my_output_1": output_1
}

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.summary()
```

The model summary has the correct name for the input layer, but does not have the correct names for either output layer, despite the fact that the name was specified both in the output dict keys, as well as the layer name itself.

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 my_input_0 (InputLayer)        [(None, 10)]         0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)                (None, 1)            11          ['my_input_0[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 tf.math.log_1 (TFOpLambda)     (None, 1)            0           ['dense_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 tf.math.exp_1 (TFOpLambda)     (None, 1)            0           ['dense_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 11
Trainable params: 11
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

It's possible to work around this issue by wrapping the outputs in `keras.Layer()`:

```py
output_0 = keras.layers.Layer(name="my_output_0")(tf.math.log(x))
output_1 = keras.layers.Layer(name="my_output_1")(tf.math.exp(x))
```

But this adds extra layers to the model; I imagine the runtime cost is negligible, but it feels ugly and clogs up the model summary.

Is there a better way to accomplish this output naming? Remember, the core issue is that a Tensorflow Serving model sets the output names based on the output layer names, which are the same as those displayed in the summary.

Comment: Use a `lambda` layer to wrap the logic: `tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.log(x),  name="my_output_0")(x)`

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use `model.layers._name` for every layer you want to rename.
For example:

```
model.layers[2]._name="my_output_0"
model.summary()
```

This should give the output:
[image]